# Correct way to use phonegap & jquery mobile with multiple html pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application which uses jquery mobile and consists of a few html pages each with a few jquery page elements within them. On a desktop browser it all works fine but when I load it on my android device (running 2.3) the first page looks fine, but whenever you click a link (lets say from index.html -> logged-in-menu.html jquery mobile doesn't seem to kick in and no stylings are applied. If I then go BACK to index.html from the current page then index.html is left unstyled.

So is there a *correct* way to move between separate html pages? I don't get any browser errors so everything *seems* to be working fine but none of the styles or features of jqm are applied.

Just so everyone is on the same page, the links use data-ajax="false" so they cause a complete page refresh (as this is required), the app can not work as a single page application so putting everything into one big html file is not an option.

Comment: can you put the source of the main html file and the html file you are transferring to `(index.html -> logged-in-menu.html)` if possible

Comment: If you're completely refreshing the page then I imagine you'll need references to the jQuery and PhoneGap/Cordova JS and CSS files in each HTML page. Have you done this?

Comment: You probably have an error in your paths. Check Logcat. Download and link locally jquery/jquery mobile and their CSS.

Comment: It is quite complicated, as I am using knockoutJS a LOTS of dynamically loaded stuff, I just omitted that from the question to simplify things. ``<a id="page-two-button" data-role="button" href="page-two.html" data-ajax="false">Page Two</a>``

Comment: @Fortis forgot to mention ALL JS, CSS and HTML is packaged locally it is a self contained application which has all assets locally and doesn't connect to the internet for any resources. I also have a build template/environment which minifies all resources contextually, although I have tried both individual resource builds and minified versions, both work fine on desktop, both exhibit same issues on handheld.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not getting styling then you either have a missing CSS document, a JS error, or you did not structure the HTML properly on the new page.

Comment: Thats the thing, there is no JS error, nothing is bubbled to Logcat. It works FINE on desktop browsers Chrome, Firefox etc. No errors whatsoever, as I use JSLint, JSTestRunner and Selenium based acceptance tests. To prove it all works as intended. The bulk of the functionality is shared between pages so if no pages worked I would understand, but as the first page works fine (Which loads lots of dynamic css, js and kicks off knockout JS bindings). So as any subsequent pages don't work (even returning to the index.html is then broken but without js errors).

Comment: It is still likely a JS or CSS error. Desktop browsers are not the internal browser. I would suggest using the built in logging to see if parts of your JS failing. Additionally if PhoneGap has a debug mode I would turn it on. I know they where adding logging functionality a while back but I have not used it since it was Alpha/Beta. Regular JS logging on Android is documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Comment: When you say built in logging what do you mean? I have tried using the hook-in debug phonegap stuff where you include the js with #someUniqueName and go to debug.phonegap.com/<guff>/someUniqueName but again no errors there. The javascript stuff is being activated as I manually put an alert in once all my dynamic stuff had loaded, and it occurred (slower than I was expecting). I would LOVE an error as I could fix it then, but currently im in limbo with it :(

Comment: Android supports JS logging to Logcat as described in my link as 'console.log("Hello World");'. While this is sufficient for basic logging I recommend you implement 'onConsoleMessage(String, int, String)' that is also described in the link from my previous comment. The error may also not be in PhoneGap but instead in JQM.

Comment: It could very well be, but it gives no errors. If I manually change something which *should* cause an error I get an error. So its not like it is not catching errors. It will tell me if a resource doesn't load (via yepnope) or if an element doesn't exist to bind to etc, so its just odd that this gives NO errors or feedback...

Comment: There is actually a bug with YepNope which has taken me forever to track down, where on android browsers it will not finish its loading so the complete event is never raised. So will give this the answer as its close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to break up the pages (and even panels within a page) into separate  template .html files dynamically loaded and render them as needed. See the tutorial on "creating mobile apps with KnockoutJS, PhoneGap, and jQuery Mobile" http://bit.ly/crmakopgjqm